# Cmake how to manage two package include same sub-project

Tags: c++, cmake, deb, cpack

I wrote an shared library project. The CMakeLists.txt in this project:

```
install(TARGETS ${library_name}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION "lib"
)

install(FILES 
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libxxx.so
  DESTINATION "lib"
)

install(DIRECTORY
    data
    DESTINATION "/opt/${project_name}"
)
```

Then, I have two project include that

```
add_subdirectory(module/xxx)
```

I use Cpack generate pkg1.deb pkg2.deb;

on installation time error occurred, trying to overwrite "libxxx.so", which is also in package "pkg1.deb", install package failed;

Now, I use dpkg with `--force-overwrite` temporarily solve this；

Is there a solution to manange this with cmake?

Comment: Simply do not install libraries of a subproject "globally", into `lib/`, where they will conflict with other packages which uses the same subproject. Install subproject's libraries e.g. into `lib/<main_project_name>/`. The problem is actually not CMake-specific.

Comment: @Tsyvarev There are also some depends file in /opt/${project_name}; I mean If there are an better solution with cmake that will be greater.

Comment: Once again, CMake installs none file which is not explicitly listed in your `CMakeLists.txt`. For avoid conflicts between files installed from different packages you need to **choose layout** of the files to install. And CMake cannot help you in the **choosing process**. The simplest way is to not install subproject's files but depends on the subproject's package, which should have all these files installed. Another way is to install subproject's files into **private** directories (assuming a subproject supports that). Once you will have a chosen layout, try to implement it in CMake.